# Passing a context to multiple InterfaceControllers?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm using reloadRootPageControllers to load 4 InterfaceControllers and I need to pass a context to each, however using the code below, only the first InterfaceController in the array receives the context.  How can I pass it to all 4?

```
let contextDictionary = ["workoutConfiguration" : workoutConfiguration, "ActivityType": selectedActivityType, "workoutManager" : workoutManager] as [String : Any]


        WKInterfaceController.reloadRootPageControllers(withNames: ["WorkoutControlsInterfaceController", "MainDisplayInterfaceController", "SpeedInterfaceController", "CaloriesAndDistanceInterfaceController"],
                                                        contexts: [contextDictionary],
                                                        orientation: .horizontal,
                                                        pageIndex: 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an array which has the same number of `contextDictionary` with `withNames` array.

```
WKInterfaceController.reloadRootPageControllers(withNames: ["WorkoutControlsInterfaceController", "MainDisplayInterfaceController", "SpeedInterfaceController", "CaloriesAndDistanceInterfaceController"],
                                                    contexts: [contextDictionary, contextDictionary, contextDictionary, contextDictionary],
                                                    orientation: .horizontal,
                                                    pageIndex: 1)
```

Comment: Never would have guessed that one! 